# ¿Cómo puedo asociar una tabla existente a un esquema creado en Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, schema, scheme

Necesito asignar un esquema que he creado a una tabla que ya existe en la bd. Se que debería ser con alter a la tabla o al esquema de la tabla. He visto varios ejemplos creando una tabla pero en mi caso no quiero crear ninguna sino asignarle el nuevo esquema a la tabla que ya existe.

Probe con esto:

```
Alter schema [Nuevo Esquema]
 Transfer [Esquema viejo].[Tabla a la que quiero el esquema]
```

Pero me dio error.

Comment: Cual error te dio?

Answer (score 2):

Desgraciadamente, es imposible corregir tu error sin saber el código que utilizaste. Probablemente sea un simple error al escribir el código, ya que lo que probaste parece ser lo correcto.

Dejo un ejemplo con todos los pasos desde crear la tabla en el esquema default, crear el esquema y mover la tabla al nuevo esquema y dejar la base de datos como estaba en un inicio. Incluyo todos los pasos para que cualquiera pueda replicarlo sin problemas.

```
--Creamos una tabla en un esquema ya existente
CREATE TABLE dbo.TablaAMover( id int);
GO

--Verificamos su esquema
SELECT s.name AS Esquema,
       t.name AS tabla
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.name = 'TablaAMover';

GO
--Creamos un nuevo esquema
CREATE SCHEMA Nuevo;
GO

--Movemos la tabla al nuevo esquema
ALTER SCHEMA Nuevo TRANSFER dbo.TablaAMover;  
GO

--Verificamos que tenga el nuevo esquema
SELECT s.name AS Esquema,
       t.name AS tabla
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE t.name = 'TablaAMover';
GO

--Dejamos la base de datos como estaba
DROP TABLE Nuevo.TablaAMover;
GO

DROP SCHEMA Nuevo;
GO
```

Comment: El error que me sale es porque no existe el objeto es decir el esquema y ya me di cuenta porque. Lamentablemente no puedo copiar todo el código ya que no lo tengo en una pc local, pero te comento en realidad no era un esquema como tal sino un esquema de particion. Lo que deseo es asociar mi tabla con el esquema de particion creado. Algo como esto: Alter table [MiTabla] add PartitionEsquema[nombre del esquema de particion]....Ya se que esta mal pero lo escribo como para que se entienda lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es algo muy distinto a lo que planteas en la pregunta. Te sugiero que redactes una nueva pregunta con lo mencionado en este comentario.

Comment: Si eso estaba pensando, gracias.